# Ridge regression in glmnet and sklearn

Tags: r, python, scikit-learn, ridge-regression, glmnet

Why does ridge regression in glmnet and sklearn give very different results?

```
library(glmnet)
X = matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5, 2, 5, 5, 3), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)
y = c(1, 0, 0, 1)
reg = glmnet(X, y, alpha = 0, lambda = 1)
coef(reg)
```

glmnet output: `0.18811436, –0.02910451, –0.04614124, 0.26402541`

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
X = np.array([[1, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2], [6, 5, 2], [5, 5, 3]])
y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
reg = Ridge(alpha = 1, fit_intercept = True, normalize = True)
reg.fit(X, y)
np.hstack((reg.intercept_, reg.coef_))
```

sklearn output: `–0.03862178, –0.0399697, –0.07276535, 0.42727921`